# Get Milliseconds for the Time of Day

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript `Date()` object and I only need the milliseconds of the current time; I don't want any dates.

```
var myDate = new Date();
// get millis only for time and not for date
```

Is there a possibility to do this?

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is:

```
var millis = myDate.getMilliseconds();
```

Comment: This only returns the millisecond part of the current time. So will be a value between 0 and 1000 no matter the time of the day, which I think is not what OP wants here.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the remainder of a day length of the epoc.

```js
var d = +(new Date());

console.log(d);
d = d % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
console.log(d);
console.log('h', d / (1000 * 60 * 60) | 0);
console.log('m', (d % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60) | 0);
console.log('s', (d % (1000 * 60)) / 1000 | 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you want the ms that have elapsed in the day current day?

You could try something like

```js
var now = new Date().getTime();
var startOfDay = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0);
var ms = now - startOfDay;

console.log(now);
console.log(startOfDay);
console.log(ms);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure is.

Step 1: Declare a variable as a date.

```
var today = new Date();
```

Step 2: Redefine variable with `.getHours()` method.

```
today = today.getHours();
```

Step 3: Divider by milliseconds in a day.

```
today = today / 86400000;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getMs() {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getMilliseconds();
    document.getElementById("setMs").innerHTML = n;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="getMs()">Click me</button>

<p id="setMs"></p>
```

Hope it helps.